# Losing linked Lists during initial and subsequent loads of simple game level data using Realm in Swift

Tags: swift3, realm, xcode8

I have a small iOS game that currently has about 20 levels. I'm using realm to store the level metadata and then linking a List of scores to each level.

Ex.

```
class Level: Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var maxTimeAllowed = 100.0
    dynamic var bonusTime = 5.0

    let scores = List<Score>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Score: Object {
    dynamic var pointsEarned = 0
    dynamic var bonusEarned = 0
}

let level3 = Level(value: ["id": "3", "maxTimeAllowed": 10.0, "bonusTime": 5.0])
```

To initially set all of the levels, in my AppDelegate, I create them, and then write them to Realm with an update. I'm doing this so I can change some of the properties/update them in the future.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add([level3], update: true)
}
```

Later in the game, I add a score to a level by:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    let score = Score(value: ["pointsEarned":score.pointsEarned, "bonusEarned":score.bonusEarned])
    level.scores.append(score)
    realm.add(level, update: true)
}
```

I know this structure is naive and needs fixing. The main problem I'm having right now is that when the game loads each time and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called. It loads the level (ex. Level 3) again, updates it, but the scores do not stick around. They're still in the DB, but now they're kine of just hanging there b/c the Realm linkage is gone.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better best practice for loading an initial set of levels (and adding levels in the future)?
2. How would I improve the structure to keep scores linked while allowing me to update level metadata?

Using Swift 3.0.2/Xcode 8/Latest version of Realm using linked binary

Answer (score 1):

When you add `level3` to the Realm, the value of each of its properties replaces the values for the existing object. This includes properties which happen to be at their default value, as there's no way to distinguish that from an explicitly set property.

If you instead do `realm.create(Level.self, ["id": "3", "maxTimeAllowed": 10.0, "bonusTime": 5.0])` only the values actually present in the dictionary will be used.

`realm.add(level, update: true)` in the second write transaction you show is a no-op assuming that `level` is an object retrieved from the Realm, and if it isn't that line will also replace the existing list of scores for the level.

Comment: Thanks! This worked and let me down the path to some more reading. Much appreciated.